# Is it Advisable to use .ashx while displaying images ?

Tags: asp.net, image, handler, image-resizing

Is it advisable to use a handler to display Images ? the issue is i cannot right click and save these images .It shows the Handler name and Asp.net Generic handler  as save type so i cant save the image but the GUI image is amazing in quality.I am showing a single image in different sizes using 2 handlers and the code works fine but if then if I don't use the Handler i have to re size them individually and then store them in different folders.

Comment: I wrote http://imageresizing.net/ to handle all the problems and sub-topics Widor brings up in the answer below. You should take a look - it's become the de-facto standard. If you're doing your own, [you should really read this list of pitfalls to avoid](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used this method on sites before, but it's only of use if your particular case is suitable. If you can do it using HTML and your images are the correct size on the server, then it's probably overkill.

If you find yourself saving several copies of the same image then you may benefit from manipulating it on the fly.

In my scenario, using a .ashx handler enabled me to upload just one large hi-res image per subject and then transform it for use in several different ways:

- Thumbnail
- Cropped image
- 'Reflection' effects (like it was above a shiny surface)
- Various galleries

Then it was just a case of calling it from a custom Image control and passing the correct parameters in.

**EDIT :** 
Regarding saving the images, I can do it fine in mine as long as I force the .ashx extension that the browser tries to give it to be JPEG (or whatever).

I can't give you a full working .ashx example, and there are so many sub-topics you'll need to consider:

- Security - only read from certain locations
- Formats - are you going to output all images in, say, JPEG, regardles of the original format?
- HttpHandlers - how to create and use them (not just for images)
- Graphics manipulation  - familiarise yourself with the `Graphics` object in .NET
- Memory streams

As a small example (in VB.NET), here's a simple method to resize an image given the new width and height:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports CustomImaging
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ImgHandler : Implements IHttpHandler


  Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    'Process the image and output it as a stream from memory

  End Sub

  Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        'a holder for the result
        Dim result As New Bitmap(width, height)
        'use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)
        Try
            'set the resize quality modes to high quality
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            'draw the image into the target bitmap
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height)
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally 'clean up resources
            If Not g Is Nothing Then g.Dispose()

        End Try
        'return the resulting image
        Return result
   End Function

   Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: That's exactly what i am talking about sir ! I just want to upload one image and then re-size it to various sizes but when i want to right click and save it. + can you help me with a sample if you have one if you only don't mind..i am quite new with this .thanks a mill !

Comment: We created a window service with a file watcher to created resized copies of images as they were uploaded by the user. You get different sizes of images but without the load of a handler. Approaches depends on you having a lot of control over your live environment of course

Comment: Bro i need help..Tell me the what i should do at this cross road ? ether use a handler and re-size 1 image using them  or use re-size the images which i guess would be loads of work at the end of the day but i am ready for that if it would be helpful at the end of the day.!

Comment: honestly - the service isn't that hard to do. It took us maybe half a day. The big caveat would be - can you install that on your live server. Do you have that kind of control. For me - i would and did write a service. It's more efficient than doing it on the fly and no harder IMHO. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using generic handlers for displaying images.

I used to use this approach, but unless the image is changing quite often, I think it is a waste of resources.

Every time a user goes to a page which contains your image in an `img` control, the browser is having to make a HTTP Request to that file, run the code, and return a streamed image.

If you are only doing this for image thumbnail purposes, for example, I would recommend saving physical versions of the thumbnail image whenever the image is uploaded throughout the app.

Another advantage of this, is that images don't error as much as code!

Comment: Sounds like you should look at http://imageresizing.net/ Disk caching eliminates the overhead, although the image resizing itself is highly optimized anyhow.